# Adicionar metodo no ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Criei um método no **ActiveRecord::Base** e ele usa um outro método a ser definido no model, preciso validar se o método do model está definido antes de executar o que preciso, mas ele diz que sempre está indefinido, o que poderia ser?
Ex:

**Método do *ActiveRecord::Base***

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_md5
    uuid = ''
    return uuid unless Module.method_defined? :md5_fields
    md5_fields.each do |mf|
      uuid += mf if mf
    end
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest(uuid)
  end
end
```

**No model**

```
 def md5_fields
   [cep, numero, complemento, cidade]
 end
```

Quando o método do model estiver definido ele retorna o **MD5**, caso contrário uma string vazia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teste assim:

```
return uuid unless self.class.method_defined? :md5_fields
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!